# fastest option for database based caching

Tags: php, database, performance, caching

I'm fetching hotel's availability trough 3rd party services and the response is currently cached on the a folder under the webroot. The cache is file based.
But, I have several websites which fetch availability of same hotel and obviously they keep the cache on their respective sub folder of their webroots.

I want to avoid file based caching for some reasons so, I am not planning to keep a shared folder on the server for caching purpose.

As per my requirement the best option I could think of is storing the cache in  to the database. Currently I'm using shared MySQL database for all my other stuff on the websites.

**The operations that I need to be fastest are**

> 1. read cache, primary key provided (multiple read of same record should be possible)
> 2. write single row of cache
> 3. Delete expired cache and insert new cache data    OR    Update expired cache with new data

**Other Operations that I don't care if they are slower**

> 1. Viewing logs of the cache / viewing all cached records
> 2. Deleting cache in bulk

**The table structure will roughly be**

> 1. key - a hashed alphanumeric key - PRIMARY
> 2. value - the cached data - approx 1 - 4 KB data - Text
> 3. last_updated - the date & time when the cache was inserted/updated

Having the knowledge that I don't need all the features of a RDBMS I think using MySQL is not an optimum option.

I don't want to use any 3rd party paid solution.

My question is which database should I use for storing cache provided the features I need and their priority of being fast?

Comment: Why not Sqlite? Should reside in memory if data is pretty small and should do the trick of being fast.

Answer (score 0):

Caching in itself is basically a temporary database so it really depends on your definition of 'database based caching'.
The size and scalability of the application is also something to consider unless you build logic to allow different kinds of caching with the same logic.
If you mean SQL based caching then it makes sense to use MySQL since you already have that setup.
If you have a dedicated database and the data isn't too large then this should be perfectly fine but if its performance you want then consider some other caching options.

You can for e.g use Memcache which is very popular and in my opinion very easy to use:
http://memcached.org/

Another solution which I also like and is well supported is Redis.
Redis is not just a caching system but can be used for multiple different soltuions. I have actually used it as queuing system. It's a memory based cache which keeps it nice and fast:
http://redis.io/

These are both free solutions and have integrations in different programming languages.

Which language are you using to build the application?

Comment: IMHO, These solutions are designed for big data (GBs and TBs)and not for average sized data. These solutions may not be able to give their best for this size of data. Correct me if I you think otherwise.

Comment: Redis may be overkill depending on the size application but I don't think these solutions were specially designed for big data especially because Redis is a memory based caching system, I consider memcache a suitable solution for small to average sized data. I have never heard of memcache being designed or used for big data, by that point I would probably be using Redis instead. There is even a limit to how much memcache can handle. The advantage of these solutions over say MySQL is that you don't have to manually check to see if the data has expired.

Comment: The size of total cache may be of few MBs and in some rare case few hundred MBs. The problem is the cache should be readable in 2 different servers which are inter-connected in LAN. And several domains are running on these servers, Sharing of cache among these servers is necessary. Will redis or memcached be shared among 2 servers?

Comment: If I remember correctly Memcache does not support this and Redis supports clustering since the newest version. You can however host the cache on a single server and have them accessed remotely. Is this maybe an option or is there a specific reason to have the cache on multiple servers?